# ¿Comparar 2 strings en JAVA?

Tags: java, string, imprimir

El programa en si es una aplicación que se presentaría por la consola solamente. Se debe permitir el ingreso, consulta, modificaron y eliminación de estudiantes, profesores, secretarios, conserjes y calificaciones.
Se debe ingresar como un tipo de usuario y cada tipo de usuario tiene ciertas limitaciones.El administrador ingresaría todos los datos y estos de guardarían, el problema surge al momento de ingresar como un usuario tipo Estudiante, en este caso, pues este lo único que puede hacer es ver sus datos, a partir del ingreso de su Cedula de Identidad (CI). Se debería comparar la CI ingresada por teclado con la que esta en los datos, he intentado hacerlo de diversas maneras, pero o me da algún tipo de error al comprar los datos o no presenta los datos o algo similar.

Alguien me puede ayudar explicándome donde esta el error y/o como arreglarlo? o si debería modificar alguna cosa de las clases para facilitar la comparación?

Parte del código que se supone hace la comparación de (CI):(No hace la comparación correctamente)

```
case 1: //Estudiante
                do{
                    System.out.println("Qué es lo que desea hacer?");
                    System.out.println("1. Mostrar Datos");
                    System.out.println("2. Retroceder");
                    Accion=sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    ListIterator it = LE.listIterator();
                    switch(Accion){
                        case 1: //Consultar Calificaciones
                            System.out.println("Ingrese su Cedula de Identidad");
                            Aux2=sc.nextLine();
                           
                            while(it.hasNext())
                            {
                                //COMPARA LAS (CI)
                                if(it.toString().contains(Aux2))
                                {
                                    //SI EL ESTUDIANTE TIENE ESA CEDULA IMPRIME SUS DATOS
                                    System.out.println(it.next());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //SI NO LOS TIENE SIGUE CON EL SIGUIENTE OBJETO DE LA LISTA Y SIGUE EL BUCLE
                                    it.next();
                                }
                                //SE DEBERIA PONER UN MSG SI ES QUE LA CEDULA INGRESADA NO HA SIDO ENCONTRADA O ALGO
                            }
                        break;
                        
                        case 2: //Retroceder
                            Sistema=0;
                        break;
                    }
                }while(Sistema==1);
                Sistema=1;
            break;
```

Parte del código que muestra los datos:

```
public static void mostrarDatos(LinkedList lista)
    {
        Persona p;
        for(int i=0;i<lista.size();++i)
        {
            System.out.println
        ("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
            
            p=(Persona)lista.get(i);
            System.out.println(i+" - "+p.mostrar());
            
            System.out.println
        ("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
```

Parte del Código que permite el ingreso de datos:

```
public static void ingresoDatos(int Tipo,LinkedList lista)
    {
        String nombre,apellido,cedula,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestreC;
        
        String turno;
        
        int i,edad,años_servicio,año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg,cant_materias,cant_carreras;
        
        double parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion;
        
        String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestreM, id_carrera;
        
        Calificaciones calificaciones;
        Materia materias;
        List<Materia> materiasD= new ArrayList<Materia>();
        List<Materia> materias_semestre;
        materias_semestre = new ArrayList<Materia>();
        
        Fecha f_nacimiento;
        Fecha f_inicio;
        Fecha f_final;
        Fecha f_ingreso;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese su nombre:");
            nombre=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su apellido:");
            apellido=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su cedula:");
            cedula=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su edad:");
            edad=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Fecha de nacimiento (SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            f_nacimiento= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese su telefono:");
            telefono=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su direccion:");
            direccion=sc.nextLine();
            
        
        if (Tipo == 1){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su semestre:");
            semestreC=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha inicio de semestre(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_inicio= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha final de semestre(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_final= new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese Catidad Materias:");
            cant_materias=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for(i=0;i<cant_materias;i++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre Materia:");
                nombre_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Codigo Materia:");
                codigo_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Semestre Materia:");
                semestreM=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese ID Materia:");
                id_carrera=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Parcial 1 de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                parcial1=sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Parcial 2 de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                parcial2=sc.nextDouble();
                if ((parcial1+parcial2)/2<7)
                {
                    System.out.println("Ingrese Calificacion Recuperacion de la Materia "+nombre_materia);
                    recuperacion=sc.nextDouble();
                }
                else
                {
                    recuperacion=0;
                }
                sc.nextLine();
                calificaciones = new Calificaciones(parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion);
                materias= new Materia(nombre_materia,codigo_materia,semestreM,id_carrera,calificaciones);
                materias_semestre.add(materias);
            }

            lista.add(new Estudiante(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,semestreC,f_inicio,f_final,materias_semestre));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 2){
        do{
            LinkedList carreras=new LinkedList();
            System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de carreras a las que asiste:");
            cant_carreras=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for(i=0;i<cant_carreras;++i)
            {
                System.out.println("Ingrese CARRERA "+i+":");
                carrera=sc.nextLine();
                carreras.add(carrera);
            }
            System.out.println("Ingrese Catidad Materias:");
            cant_materias=sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            for(i=0;i<cant_materias;i++){
                System.out.println("Ingrese Nombre Materia:");
                nombre_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Codigo Materia:");
                codigo_materia=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese Semestre Materia:");
                semestreM=sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Ingrese ID Materia:");
                id_carrera=sc.nextLine();
                calificaciones=new Calificaciones(0,0,0);
                materias= new Materia(nombre_materia,codigo_materia,semestreM,id_carrera,calificaciones);
                materiasD.add(materias);
            }
            
            lista.add(new Profesor(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carreras,materiasD));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 3){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_ingreso=new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana o tarde):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
        
        if (Tipo == 4){
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera:");
            carrera=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(AÑO):");
            año=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MES):");
            mes=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(DIA):");
            dia=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(HORA):");
            hora=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(MINUTO):");
            min=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su Fecha ingreso(SEGUNDO):");
            seg=sc.nextInt();
            f_ingreso=new Fecha(año,mes,dia,hora,min,seg);
            System.out.println("Ingrese sus años de servicio:");
            años_servicio=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese su turno (mañana, tarde o noche):");
            turno=sc.nextLine();
            lista.add(new Secretario(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion,carrera,f_ingreso,años_servicio,turno));                
            break;
        }while(true);
        }
    }
```

Clase Estudiante

```
import java.util.*;
public class Estudiante extends Persona{
    
    protected String carrera,semestre;
    protected List<Materia> materias_semestre;
    protected Fecha f_inicio,f_final;
    
    public Estudiante(String nombre,String apellido, String cedula, int edad, Fecha f_nacimiento,String telefono,String direccion,String carrera,String semestre,Fecha f_inicio,Fecha f_final,List<Materia> materias_semestre){
        
        super(nombre,apellido,cedula,edad,f_nacimiento,telefono,direccion);
        this.carrera=carrera;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.f_inicio=f_inicio;
        this.f_final=f_final;
        this.materias_semestre=materias_semestre;
    }
    
    public String mostrar(){
        
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento.mostrarF()+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+semestre+" "+f_inicio.mostrarF()+" "+f_final.mostrarF()+"\n"+materias_semestre);
    }

    public String toString(){
        
        return (nombre+" "+apellido+" "+cedula+" "+edad+" "+f_nacimiento.mostrarF()+" "+telefono+" "+direccion+" "+carrera+" "+semestre+" "+f_inicio.mostrarF()+" "+f_final.mostrarF()+"\n"+materias_semestre);
    }
    
}
```

Clase Materia

```
public class Materia {
    
    protected String nombre_materia,codigo_materia, semestre, id_carrera;
    protected Calificaciones calificaciones;
    
    public Materia(String nombre_materia,String codigo_materia, String semestre, String id_carrera, Calificaciones calificaciones)
    {
        this.nombre_materia=nombre_materia;
        this.codigo_materia=codigo_materia;
        this.semestre=semestre;
        this.id_carrera=id_carrera;
        this.calificaciones=calificaciones;
    }
    
    public String toString(){

            return "\nMATERIA: "+nombre_materia+"/"+codigo_materia+"/"+semestre+"/"+id_carrera+" "+calificaciones.toString()+"\n";
        
        
    }
}
```

Clase Calificaciones

```
public class Calificaciones {
    
    protected double parcial1,parcial2,recuperacion;
    
    public Calificaciones(double parcial1,double parcial2,double recuperacion)
    {
        this.parcial1=parcial1;
        this.parcial2=parcial2;
        this.recuperacion=recuperacion;
        //this.nota_final=nota_final;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        
        if(parcial1+parcial2+recuperacion==0)
        {
            return ".";
        }
        else
        {
            if ((parcial1+parcial2)/2>=7){
            
            return "CALIFICACIONES --> Parcial 1: "+parcial1+"/ Parcial 2: "+parcial2+"/ Nota Final: "+((parcial1+parcial2)/2);
            }
            else{
                return "CALIFICAIONES --> Parcial 1: "+parcial1+"/ Parcial 2: "+parcial2+"/ Recuperación: "+recuperacion+"/ Nota Final: "+((((parcial1+parcial2)/2)*0.6)+(recuperacion*0.4));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Intenta editar tu pregunta y añadir solo el código relevante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que la lista que recorres es una lista de estudiantes, tu error esta en la comparación. Estas comparando el `toString()` de un estudiante contra una identificación(que puede ser numérica o alfanumérica.). Para explicarme mejor te planteo un ejemplo:

```
aux = "174"; // a modo de prueba inicializo aux con este valor

Persona e = new Estudiante("Carlos","Rivera","17485052",35); //a modo de ejemplo ingreso solo esos valores y omito el resto.

System.out.println(e.toString());
```

por pantalla vas a ver:

```
Carlos Rivera 17485052 35

//en este ejemplo contains() va a devolver TRUE, porque la cedula contiene la secuencia "174". como observaras esta validando "mal".
```

como veras, en algunos casos puede validar bien y en otros no, porque le estas pasando toda la cadena con el `toString()`. Lo correcto seria que en Estudiante tengas los `Sets()` y `gets()` por cada atributo y comparar directamente contra el atributo. Siguiendo los patrones GRASP, el metodo que tendria que comparar, deberia estar en la clase estudiante.

A modo de resolver tu problema de forma sencilla te paso el fragmento que deberias modificar:

```
while(it.hasNext())
                            {
                                //COMPARA LAS (CI)
                                if(it.getCedula.equalsIgnoreCase(Aux2))//<-----aca debes corregir
                                {
                                    //SI EL ESTUDIANTE TIENE ESA CEDULA IMPRIME SUS DATOS
                                    System.out.println(it.next());
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //SI NO LOS TIENE SIGUE CON EL SIGUIENTE OBJETO DE LA LISTA Y SIGUE EL BUCLE
                                    it.next();//
                                }
                                //SE DEBERIA PONER UN MSG SI ES QUE LA CEDULA INGRESADA NO HA SIDO ENCONTRADA O ALGO
                            }
```

Si decides hacerlo dentro de la clase estudiante deberia ser algo asi:

```
public boolean esMiCedula(String cedula)
    {
        //indico las 3 formas de comparar, podes utilizar la que quieras o te convenga
        if(cedula != null)
        return nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(cedula);// compara si las cadenas son iguales, no distingue mayusculas de minuscula. Para este metodo "Hola" y "hola" son iguales.
        return nombre.equals(cedula);//compara las cadenas, pero si distingue mayusculas de minusculas. Para este metodo "Hola" no es lo mismo que "hola"
    }
```

Algo que observe, en los atributos deberías usar `Private` y no `Protected`.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que veo el *string* lo obtienes de un `Scanner`, entonces creo que lo mejor será usar el método [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object **that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.**

Es decir, que te va a devolver el booleano `true` si el argumento respresenta la misma secuencia de caracteres.

```
String foo = "Foo";
String bar = sc.nextLine();

if (bar.equals(foo)) {
    /*...*/
```

Pienso que esto es más eficiente que usar `contains()`, debido a que se puede ingresar un string **no igual, pero sí parecido.** Recordar que el operador `==` entre strings **compara referencias de objetos en memoria, y no contenido.**

- Tal vez te interese leer [*How do I compare strings in Java?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Saludos.